# Force InfoPath form to open in Browser

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I created an InfoPath form that uses VB code to push fields into a custom list I created on a SharePoint 2007 site.  This part works.

I "published" the form into a form library.

I changed the settings on that form library to open items in the browser and allow editing of content types.

In InfoPath under Form Settings I chose the compatibility setting to allow this form to be opened in a browser, I linked to my Forms service online, and ran the design checker.  No errors.

When I try to open it in the browser using the "Edit in Browser" setting I get this error message:

> This form template is not currently
>   browser-enabled. It must either be
>   republished as a browser-enabled form,
>   or opened using Microsoft Office
>   InfoPath 2007.

No matter what I do, the form will not open in the browser.  This is all I want.  Did I miss something??

Comment: Have you signed the form with a certificate in the "Security and Trust" screen?

Comment: I've set the security and trust, the one thing I noticed is that it says "An Administrator must approve this form template before it can be filled out by the browser".  I am an "Owner" on my SharePoint site but I am not a site-collection-admin, can I perform this task??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload your form thru Central Administration because you use code in your form. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772110.aspx) MSDN acticle.

Comment: I removed the code, changed the submit connection from an updatelistitem to the code-less submit-form-to-library, and still cannot open a code-less form in the browser...

Comment: At the core of it, you're correct.  I need a certificate issued by a site collection administrator in order for the environment to trust a form that I have set custom and explicit trust settings on that contains code.